# Clearing the contents of a File Upload

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, upload

I want to clear the contents of a File Upload Control. How can i do this

Any Help

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to clear the value of a file input right?

```
document.getElementById('file_input_id').value = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to clear the input dialogue(jQuery):

```
$('form')[0].reset();
```

works for me